# Convert Timestamp(Nanoseconds format) to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp with Nanoseconds format that I want convert this to datetime in but I get error

```
import datetime

example_timestamp= '1629617204525776950'

example_timestamp= int(example_timestamp)


timestamp_to_date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(example_timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
```

Comment: "I get error"—please _always_ include complete error messages. "An error" isn't very helpful for troubleshooting. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `=` to assign values and not `:`

You can do like this.

```
import datetime
example_timestamp =  int('1629617204525776950')

timestamp_to_date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(example_timestamp/1000000000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
print(timestamp_to_date_time)
```

```
2021-08-22 07:26:44,525777
```